# Does Wolfram Alpha fail for $x^x$?

Tags: real-analysis, graphing-functions

[WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/) generates the following graphic for $f_{(x)} = x^x$:

> [image]
>
> ### [$f_{(x)} = x^x$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5Ex)

Can anyone explain me why this graphic looks like above? I mean why the real part for negative, non-integer, but rational numbers looks like that?for $0^0$?

To clarify my question:

We know that:

$$a^{m/n} = sqrt(a^m, n)$$

So, for example:

$${-1.1}^{-1.1} = 1 / {sqrt({-1.1}^{11}, 10)}$$ that is a complex number, not a real one

Comment: Downvoter, please feel free to comment

Comment: (I didn't downvote). What is your concrete question?

Comment: @Listing Please see my edit. ${-1.1}^{-1.1}$ is not a real number, it is a complex number.

Comment: Note that we can rewrite $f(x)=x^x$ as $f(x)=e^{x\ln x}$.  Then we can pick one complex branch of $\ln x$ for $x\in (-\infty,0)$ and use all-real numbers for $x\in(0,\infty)$.

Comment: @abiessu No, we can't use $lnx$ because we are forced to use $(0, ∞)$ interval for $x$. My question is about the negative numbers.

Comment: @Johnツ: my comment is intended to extend $x$ to the complex numbers, then we would use the complex logarithm to evaluate $\ln x$.  Otherwise, you are right, $\ln -k$ for positive $k$ is meaningless...

Comment: Complex numbers are of the form $a+ib$, where $a$ is the "real part" and $b$ is the "imaginary part". The graph simply plots both separately, and for positive values of $x$ considers the real number $x^x$ to be of the form $a+i\cdot 0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By definition $x^x = \exp(x \log(x))$.  Presumably Mathematica is using the principal branch of the logarithm.  Then for $x < 0$, $\log(x) = \log(|x|) + i \pi$, and so $x^x = \exp(x \log |x|) (\cos(\pi x) + i \sin(\pi x))$.

Answer (score 3):

The point at $0^0$ does not exist, however the points very near it and the limit $x^x$ as $x\to 0$ do exist.  As for the behavior of the graph in the negative real numbers, $x^x=(-a)^{-a}$ for some positive $a$ in the real numbers.  By Euler's identity, $e^{\pi i}+1=0$, so we can write $-a$ as $e^{\pi i}a$, and $(e^{\pi i}a)^{-a}=e^{-a\pi i}a^{-a}$.  Since $e^{\theta i}=\cos \theta+i\sin \theta$, we have $x^x=(-x)^x(\cos (x\pi)+i\sin(x\pi))$ for negative $x$, which is the graph Wolfram is giving you (note that some of the claims made here cannot simply be assumed, but this is just so you understand why Wolfram is making funny shapes.).